# Kernel of a conjugation map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $$X=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
If $M$ is any orthogonal matrix on a vector space $V$ of dimension $2$. I noted that $M$ can be written as $$M= \frac{M-XMX}{2} + \frac{M+XMX}{2},$$ the first summand is denoted by $P_M$ and the second is denoted by $Q_M$. I also saw that $P_M X= XP_M$ and $Q_M X=-XQ_M$, i.e. $ $ conmutes (resp. anticonmutes) with $P_M$ (resp. $Q_M$).

How can I find $\ker P_M$ and $\ker Q_M$? I believe that the rank-nullity theorem can help me, but I’m not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume we are working over $\Bbb R$.

$O(2)$ consists in rotations and rotations multiplied by  $\begin {pmatrix}-1\quad 0\\0\quad 1\end {pmatrix}$ or $\begin {pmatrix}1\quad 0\\0\quad -1\end {pmatrix}$.

Recall that rotations are the $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta\quad -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta\quad \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$.

Take a rotation, call it $R$.  Then $XRX=2R$.

Thus $P_R=-\frac R2$.

Similarly $Q_R=\frac {3R}2$.

Since $R$ has trivial kernel,  so do $P_R$ and $Q_R$.

I leave the case $\det M=-1$ to you.